# resizes image inside col-md-12 class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsiveness

I created a responsive site but some of the images dont resize as I want them to.
See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```css
#img1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-size: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6" id="mision">
        <img src="imagenes/MISION.png" id="img1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="vision">
        <img src="imagenes/VISION.png" id="img2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" id="servicios">
        <img src="imagenes/SERVICIOS.png" id="img3">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the `img` inside the `div` element with `col-md...` should have a width in percentage, like `width: 100%` and it will fill the `width` of its parent `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a fixed width in the CSS for your image element, try changing to a percentage width, e.g.:

```
#img1{
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-size:20%;
}
```

Then the width of the image should resize with your column.